# Getting "E:Error in /sdcard/.zip (status 7)" while upgrading Android Nexus 4.0.1 to 4.1.x (Jelly bean)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-s

I tried to install Jelly Bean (4.1.1) onto the Nexus S handset following the instructions from [here](http://dottech.org/74711/how-to-update-nexus-s-to-jelly-bean-android-4-1-x/).

Later, I noticed that the Nexus should have at least 4.0.3 to upgrade to 4.1.x.

So I tried to install 4.0.3 following the instruction from [here](http://dottech.org/25324/how-to-update-nexus-s-to-ice-cream-sandwich-android-4-x/%22).

But each and every time I'm having the error -

> E:Error in /sdcard/filename.zip (Status 7)

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please clarify the following: Is the bootloader unlocked? If yes, then Ok, did the first install worked when following the instruction from the first link you've enclosed? What particular model of Nexus do you have? GSM/LTE?

Comment: Yes the bootloader is unlocked and it never worked for either of the instruction. And it is a GSM Nexus S phone.

Comment: Right, status 7 is a verification error due to one of many, such as build.prop failure check, not enough space, corrupted zip file, etc. You have access to recovery and `adb` while in recovery? if so, look for `recovery.log`, and pull it down via `adb`, and post it here.

Comment: Ok.. Here's the log file http://sushi.usask.ca/androidfiles/last_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is simple, as I have suspected, there's a verification mis-match in the `build.prop`, see below,

```
Starting recovery on Fri Jan  4 20:43:32 2013
can't open /dev/tty0: No such file or directory
framebuffer: fd 3 (480 x 800)
ClockworkMod Recovery v5.0.2.0
recovery filesystem table
=========================
  0 /tmp ramdisk (null) (null)
  1 /sdcard vfat /dev/block/platform/s3c-sdhci.0/by-name/media (null)
  2 /system ext4 /dev/block/platform/s3c-sdhci.0/by-name/system (null)
  3 /cache yaffs2 cache (null)
  4 /data ext4 /dev/block/platform/s3c-sdhci.0/by-name/userdata (null)
  5 /misc mtd misc (null)
  6 /boot mtd boot (null)
  7 /recovery mtd recovery (null)
  8 /bootloader mtd bootloader (null)
  9 /radio mtd radio (null)

W:Unable to get recovery.fstab info for /sd-ext during fstab generation!
I:Completed outputting fstab.
I:Processing arguments.
Fixing execute permissions for /cache
mtd: successfully wrote block at 0
I:Set boot command "boot-recovery"
I:Checking arguments.
I:device_recovery_start()
Command: "/sbin/recovery"

ro.secure=0
ro.allow.mock.location=1
ro.debuggable=1
persist.service.adb.enable=1
ro.build.id=GRJ22
ro.build.display.id=GRJ90
ro.build.version.incremental=121341
ro.build.version.sdk=10
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=2.3.5
ro.build.date=Mon Sep  5 11:04:10 PDT 2011
ro.build.date.utc=0
ro.build.type=eng
ro.build.user=koush
ro.build.host=Koushik-Lion.local
ro.build.tags=test-keys
ro.product.model=Nexus S
ro.product.brand=google
ro.product.name=soju
ro.product.device=crespo
ro.product.board=herring
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=samsung
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=US
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.board.platform=s5pc110
ro.build.product=crespo
ro.build.description=soju-user 2.3.4 GRJ22 121341 release-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=google/soju/crespo:2.3.4/GRJ22/121341:user/release-keys
rild.libpath=/vendor/lib/libsec-ril.so
rild.libargs=-d /dev/ttyS0
ro.sf.lcd_density=240
keyguard.no_require_sim=true
ro.opengles.version=131072
wifi.interface=eth0
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=15
dalvik.vm.heapsize=32m
ro.rommanager.developerid=cyanogenmod
ro.url.legal=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html
ro.url.legal.android_privacy=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/privacy.html
ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-google
ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist=GoogleGuest
ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode=1
ro.com.android.dateformat=MM-dd-yyyy
ro.com.android.dataroaming=false
ro.config.ringtone=Playa.ogg
ro.config.notification_sound=regulus.ogg
ro.config.alarm_alert=Alarm_Beep_03.ogg
ro.ril.enable.managed.roaming=1
ro.ril.oem.nosim.ecclist=911,112,999,000,08,118,120,122,110,119,995
ro.ril.emc.mode=2
ro.modversion=CyanogenMod-7.1.0-RC1-NS-KANG
ro.kernel.android.checkjni=1
ro.setupwizard.mode=OPTIONAL
dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags=m=y
net.bt.name=Android
net.change=net.bt.name
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt
ro.factorytest=0
ro.serialno=3334E1630CFF00EC
ro.bootmode=unknown
ro.baseband=I9020XXKI1
ro.carrier=ATT
ro.bootloader=I9020XXKL1
ro.hardware=herring
ro.revision=16
init.svc.recovery=running
init.svc.adbd=running

I:Checking for extendedcommand...
I:Skipping execution of extendedcommand, file not found...
mtd: successfully wrote block at 0
I:Set boot command ""

-- Installing: /sdcard/VQ8PQk_V.zip
mtd: successfully wrote block at 0
I:Set boot command "boot-recovery"
Finding update package...
I:Update location: /sdcard/VQ8PQk_V.zip
Opening update package...
Installing update...
script aborted: assert failed: file_getprop("/system/build.prop", "ro.build.fingerprint") == "google/soju/crespo:2.3.6/GRK39F/189904:user/release-keys" ||
       file_getprop("/system/build.prop", "ro.build.fingerprint") == "google/soju/crespo:4.0.3/IML74K/239410:user/release-keys"
assert failed: file_getprop("/system/build.prop", "ro.build.fingerprint") == "google/soju/crespo:2.3.6/GRK39F/189904:user/release-keys" ||       file_getprop("/system/build.prop", "ro.build.fingerprint") == "google/soju/crespo:4.0.3/IML74K/239410:user/release-keys"
E:Error in /sdcard/VQ8PQk_V.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
mtd: successfully wrote block at 0
I:Set boot command ""
```

The `ro.build.fingerprint` contains this **google/soju/crespo:2.3.4/GRJ22/121341:user/release-keys** but the update performed a verification check on the fingerprint which resulted in mis-match and there-by producing `Error code 7`.

Notice the last few lines of the `recovery.log`, i.e. the update was expecting the handset to have this version of Gingerbread - **google/soju/crespo:2.3.6/GRK39F/189904:user/release-keys** OR expecting Ice Cream Sandwich **google/soju/crespo:4.0.3/IML74K/239410:user/release-keys**

This is meaning, that the version of Gingerbread on your handset is too old for the update to work. (Its Gingerbread 2.3.4 that is on it!) *am not 100% sure how this recovery is showing the fingerprint as GB 2.3.4 if the OP states in the comments that the handset is running ICS 4.0.1*

So to resolve the issue, you need to flash to <s>Gingerbread v 2.3.6</s> Ice Cream Sandwich v.4.0.3 first, then apply the update and it should work then.

## Edit

It transpires the OP is running ICS v. 4.0.1, the update script was performing a check for either 2.3.6 or 4.0.3 which is something that I have missed inadvertently.

Comment: But when i check from the system settings of the phone, it shows 4.0.1

Comment: Wait what? Hummm... you are on ICS right? You're confusing me now with the enclosing of the recovery log...

Comment: Well, I believe, the phone was originally with 2.3.4 when it was bought, but later it was upgraded to ICS ..

Comment: ahhh... let me edit the answer again....gotcha! wait, if recovery is saying the build prop's property is claiming to be 2.3.4, yet on your phone is 4.0.1, clearly the verification check is **also** checking for 4.0.3...

Comment: Right, try flashing ICS v 4.0.3 first and then apply the update, it should work then. :)

Comment: In my question I mentioned that I tried that too but still had the same issue :(

Comment: You **are** running ICS 4.0.1? right? Grab the `build.prop` from that - chances are the fingerprint keys don't match!

Comment: Here's the build.prop file - http://sushi.usask.ca/androidfiles/build.prop

Comment: Join in chat please! :)

Comment: Something is not right - you made a statement a while ago, that the phone settings is showing 4.0.1, *But when i check from the system settings of the phone, it shows 4.0.1 – Pow 42 mins ago* yet the build prop is showing this fingerprint **ro.build.fingerprint=google/soju/crespo:2.3.7/GWK74/185293:user/release-keys** - what gives there?

Comment: `ro.build.id=GWK74` is definitely Gingerbread 2.3.7, so either you're being pranked into believing you're running ICS 4.0.1 or that you pulled the `build.prop` from elsewhere... the truth?

Comment: Well, I have no proof that I could show and I'm not very willing to waste my time pulling the build.prop from somewhere else. And I posted here cause I was having issues, if I could understand what's happening then I would have solved myself. Anyways, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: The problem is simple, you're not running ICS as you're lead to believe because the property `ro.build.display.id=cm_crespo-userdebug 4.0.1 ICS_MR0 eng.koush.20111125.172824 test-keys` is conflicting with the following `ro.build.fingerprint=google/soju/crespo:2.3.7/GWK74/185293:user/release-keys` hence why I am sceptical of what's going on. The fingerprint does not match with the display property. Any explanation for that? One or the other **should** match, along with the `ro.build.id=GWK74`

Comment: Ok Now I concentrated on that and installed ICS 4.0.3. Now I'm trying to install 4.0.4 and it's giving me the error E:Error in /tmp/sideload/package.zip (Status 7)

Comment: Alright, can you confirm that the fingerprint matches? If it does, and you're still getting the `Status (7)` error code, check if you have enough space?