# Flashing Cyanogenmod9 - Kernel via Odin

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, rom-flashing, odin

EDIT: I think the question is more confusing than helpful. I leave it up simply because something else has been closed as a duplicate to this.
My problem was finally solved by flashing a completely fresh stock android.

With my Galaxy S i9000 (galaxysmtd), I can only access download and recovery mode after flashing some recovery kernel via odin.
The latter was done to escape the boot loop that my installed cyanogenmod 9 was stuck in.

Installing the cyanogenmod cm-9.1.0-galaxysmtd.zip from the sdcard from within the recovery mode gives me an error 7. 
This is supposedly because the recovery kernel I flashed was unfit.

My idea now is to flash only the kernel of the cyanogenmod-9.1.0-galaxysmtd as an odin-pda file, boot into recovery again and to then install the full ROM that is still on my sdcard, which should be possible then.

Because I can't boot the phone normally, I don't know how to put anything on the sdcard manually and have to use odin.

I have been reading though a lot of threads now, but the nomenclature seems to be used in such an inconsistent way that googling the right thing is almost impossible. I hope I expressed myself in sufficient clarity.

Comment: Are you talking about extracting a kernel from CM, and to flash that with Odin? Am not sure exactly what your question is....

Comment: No, I assumed that there exists a seperate kernel for CM9?

Comment: There's a reason why you got the error code 7, its not just kernel is "unfit" for the handset, could be the wrong fingerprint,out of space,existing ROM's fingerprint mismatches...check the `recovery.log` file in within the recovery partition, it will clue you in on the exact reason!

Comment: How could I do that? I mean, how to read out the recovery.log ?

Comment: See this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36898/getting-eerror-in-sdcard-zip-status-7-while-upgrading-android-nexus-4-0-1/36907#36907) in which I answered, to save repeating, boot into recovery, use `adb pull recovery.log` from that and that should give you the answer you're looking for. The OP in the question of that linky I enclosed was confused about his scenario... this will shed some light into understanding why the error 7 occurred.

Comment: @t0mm13b This here is my full recovery.log: http://pastebin.com/vrEPBcfE

Comment: There's your answer! Your existing ROM's fingerprint does not match! What existing ROM did you have running prior to attempting to flash?

Comment: @t0mm13b I had Cyanogenmod9.1.0 running, which suddenly didn't boot any more. Then I flashed CWM Recovery v2.5.1.0 SOK ULFK, which I am using now to boot into recovery.

Comment: Why did CM 9.1 *suddenly didn't boot any more*? What did you exactly?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that I removed my battery with the phone not switched off. I was on a flight back from holidays, so I haven't been doing anything hacky with it in quite a while. This guy here seems to have the same problem (in german): http://www.android-hilfe.de/root-hacking-modding-fuer-samsung-galaxy-s/280516-cm9-ploetzlicher-bootloop-mit-cyanogenmod-2.html#post3785877

Comment: Sounds like a buggy kernel! Try flashing a different kernel, there's a few from XDA site.... :) Do let us know how that goes for you :)

Comment: I have trouble finding my way on XDA. Could you give me nudge into the direcction of a page there where I can find suitable kernels?

Comment: [XDA thread for i9000](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=656)

Comment: I can see the stock roms but is there something that would make my CM9 work again? I mean, I flash a kernel and can boot into CM9 again?

Comment: @t0mm13b, I finally solved it by figuring out how to flash stock rom and doing it. I am thinking about deleting this whole thread since it is probably only going to cause confusion among future googlers.

Answer (score 1):

The key lines to understand why Error 7 occurred is from the `recovery.log` as shown here:

```
-- Installing: SDCARD:cm-9.1.0-galaxysmtd.zip
Finding update package...
I:Update location: SDCARD:cm-9.1.0-galaxysmtd.zip
Opening update package...
I:Update file path: /mnt/sdcard/cm-9.1.0-galaxysmtd.zip
Installing update...
I:Trying update-binary.
script aborted: assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "galaxys" || getp
rop("ro.build.product") == "galaxys" ||
       getprop("ro.product.device") == "galaxysmtd" || getprop("ro.build.product
") == "galaxysmtd" ||
       getprop("ro.product.device") == "GT-I9000" || getprop("ro.build.product")
 == "GT-I9000" ||
       getprop("ro.product.device") == "GT-I9000M" || getprop("ro.build.product"
) == "GT-I9000M" ||
       getprop("ro.product.device") == "GT-I9000T" || getprop("ro.build.product"
) == "GT-I9000T"
assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "galaxys" || getprop("ro.build.pr
oduct") == "galaxys" ||        getprop("ro.product.device") == "galaxysmtd" || g
etprop("ro.build.product") == "galaxysmtd" ||        getprop("ro.product.device"
) == "GT-I9000" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "GT-I9000" ||        getprop("
ro.product.device") == "GT-I9000M" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "GT-I9000M"
 ||        getprop("ro.product.device") == "GT-I9000T" || getprop("ro.build.prod
uct") == "GT-I9000T"
E:Error in /mnt/sdcard/cm-9.1.0-galaxysmtd.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

The fingerprint on the existing ROM, by way of the property `ro.product.device` or `ro.build.product` which is found in `/system/build.prop` did not match the expected one of the following:

- galaxys
- galaxysmtd
- GT-I9000
- GT-I9000M
- GT-I9000T

In theory, you could edit the `build.prop`, and change it for this to work, but comes with a big fat juicy warning - "***The actions in changing the build.prop's two properties could result in a soft-brick***" :)

Comment: I do have a i9000. So it is NOT in kernel, but in the ROM? I guess the best would be to flash something via Odin?

Comment: Can you pull in the `build.prop`, you may be able to get away with changing it to make this work...? Disclaimer: you are on your own and am not responsible for any soft-bricks... ok? :) Paste it and let's have a looksy :)

Comment: my /system -folder contains only "ls" and "bin" and is empty otherwise. Shouldn't the build.prop be there? Looks like this: http://pastebin.com/nDgXrNmg

Comment: That looks like to be a recovery's own `/system`, can you not mount the real `/system` where android fully boots up into?

Comment: I don't quite understand, how should I mount that and where should I find it?

Comment: Is there not a mount option on the menu from within recovery itself?

Comment: There is such an option, but it says: `Can't mount /dev/block/st19 to /system[...]`