# android 4.2.1 installation error on N7000 error

Tags: rom-flashing, 4.2-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flashing Cyanogenmod9 - Kernel via Odin](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37992/flashing-cyanogenmod9-kernel-via-odin)

I have a galaxy N7000 4.1.1 and tried to upgrade it to 4.2.1 but it shows and error when installing the system a such error# 7 that has to be with Internal space I've heard.

Can anybody please tell me how to fix it.. I have the 4.2.1 system and the google apps for this. But this is not letting me upgrade my android.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the method you used to upgrade? Odin, Clockwork Recovery? Can you post the exact error you see. And what ROM are you trying to flash?

Comment: Additional info would be really helpful. Else: There's also the heimdall flash software to do it http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/